# Elegant way to setup high-priority/low-priority route consumers of sqs with Camel RoutePolicy?

Tags: apache-camel, amazon-sqs

I have two SQS queues: one meant for low priority and another meant for high-priority messages. The logic is meant to be don't touch the messages on the low-priority queue unless the high-priority queue is empty.

```
SuspendLowPriorityRoutePolicy suspendLowPriorityRoutePolicy = new SuspendLowPriorityRoutePolicy(LOW_PRIORITY_ROUTE_ID, camelContext);

        from(UriBuilder.buildSqsUri(sqsProperties)).routeId(LOW_PRIORITY_ROUTE_ID)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log, "NON-PRIORITY: ${body}");

        from(UriBuilder.buildPrioritySqsUri(sqsProperties)).routeId(HIGH_PRIORITY_ROUTE_ID)
                .routePolicy(suspendLowPriorityRoutePolicy)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log, "PRIORITY: ${body}");
```

Both of these consumers have their `concurrentConsumers` property set to 1, meaning they will process a single message at a time.

Right now, I have these two routes setup to consume messages off the queues simultaneously. What I would like is for a message that comes in to the high-priority route triggers the cessation of the low-priority route. To try to get this functionality, I tried using a route policy that stops the low-priority queue when a new exchange is started on the high-priority route:

(Snippet from `SuspendLowPriorityRoutePolicy`)

```
 @Override
    public void onExchangeBegin(Route route, Exchange exchange) {
        Route lowPriorityRoute = context.getRoute(lowPriorityRouteId);
        ServiceStatus routeStatus = context.getRouteStatus(lowPriorityRouteId);
        if (!routeStatus.isStopped()) {
            try {
                lock.lock();
                log.info("High priority request came in, stopping consumer");
                stopConsumer(lowPriorityRoute.getConsumer());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception stopping consumer " + e);
                handleException(e);
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I am unsure about how to go about re-starting the low-priority consumer. The other hooks provided by the Camel `RoutePolicy` allow overriding `onExchangeDone` but at that point the logic should be to restart the low-priority consumer only if the high-priority queues is empty. I don't think there is a way to check if the queue is empty, we could check the `ApproximateNumberOfMessages` attribute on the exchange done hook but that may be inaccurate.

Another thought would to have a scheduled background poller that checks the inFlightRequestsRepository of the `CamelContext` and restarts the the low priority queues only if the high priority route has no inflight requests.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the most simple way I can think of, is, to **consume the high priority messages with much more consumers than the low priority messages**. That way, a high priority message is typically consumed very fast, while low priority messages could pile up and therefore have to wait.

However, the **low priority consumers will still process messages**, no matter how much more high priority messages are processed at the same time.

---

A bit closer to your use case is to **use [JMS priorities](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSPriority--)**.

You could **consume both queues the same way** and simply set a **different JMS priority on the message of each queue**. For example standard priority of 4 for low-priority messages and a priority of 8 for high-priority messages.

Then you **forward the messages of both consumers to a third queue**. So in this third queue the high and low priority messages arrive mixed, but each message with the appropriate priority set.

Then you **attach a consumer to the third queue** and due to the message priorities, the **high priority messages should be consumed first**. The low priority messages are only consumed if the queue contains no high priority messages.

However, there are some things to keep in mind:

- Using message priority **reorders messages in the queue** as needed. This can slow down the performance of a queue with a lot of messages.
- **Message priority must probably be activated on your broker or queue**. Otherwise the priorities are ignored. Search for a priority example with your broker to check this.
- I am not sure, but I think there are also **some flags on the JMS connection to respect priorities** on the consumer
- You have to **keep the consumer prefetch low**. If your consumer prefetches 1000 messages with low-priority it processes them all before doing anything else. No matter if in the meantime a high priority message arrives in the queue. The bigger the prefetch the more low prio messages could be processed before a newly arrived high prio message is processed.